# Hostname keeps turning back to localhost

Tags: centos, hostname

I am trying to change the hostname of a CentOS6 system and somehow it keeps returning back to localhost.

Basically, I am using: "hostname new_name" as a superuser, and it works.
Then when I log in sometimes later, it forgets the new name and turns back to "localhost". Is there any suggestion what I did miss?
I am using DHCP with reserved IP addresses, it is important.

Comment: Add `HOSTNAME=yourhostname` to your `/etc/sysconfig/network`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `/etc/sysconfig/network` with a text editor like vim or nano.

Specify the desired hostname on the line:

```
HOSTNAME=ExamplePC
```